# JQuery lazy loading doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I have the following to lazy-load images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // lazy load images
    var win = $(window);
    win.on('load resize scroll', function() {
        var viewport = {
            top: win.scrollTop(),
            left: win.scrollLeft()
        };
        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

        // cycle through all images (within visible content) and update src attributes
        $('img[data-src]').each(function() {
            var bounds = $(this).offset();
            bounds.right = bounds.left + $(this).outerWidth();
            bounds.bottom = bounds.top + $(this).outerHeight();

            // if image is within viewable area, display it
            if (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right ||
                  viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom)) {
                var img = $(this).attr('data-src');
                if (img) {
                    $(this).attr('src', img);
                    $(this).removeAttr('data-src');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What I've noticed (at least in Chrome), however, is that sometimes the images won't initially *load*, but show up as soon as I start scrolling. Any idea why or what is wrong?

**EDIT:** here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evffg0cz/) although reproducing the problem seems to be completely sporadic, I don't know what exactly causes it... Hence why I'm here.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added a jsfiddle, not sure what more I can give you.

Comment: it is the condition, where you compare `viewport` and `bounds` - output them to `console.log` and you will see that only images within the viewport are loaded on `load` event. Remember that, without `src` set and the actual picture loaded, the bounded rectangle for `img` tag is small, browser-specific size.

Comment: Could it be that before any images load, all images are collapsed to 0px height, thus triggering the load for all images immediately?

Comment: See this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rj64bevj/

Comment: @Igor if that is the case, why would it work most of the time? and how would I fix it?

Comment: @mistermartin have you experimented with `console.log`? what console output do you see?

Comment: @Igor on success viewport (top: 0 right: 1261 bottom: 942 left: 0) bounds (top: 262 right: 323 bottom: 317 left: 179), when the images fail to load the console doesn't log anything. it's almost as if `$('img[data-src]').each(function() {` never gets called. the source still shows `data-src` attributes even though the javascript files successfully loaded

Comment: @mistermartin aren't you supposed to have five bounds - from your jsfiddle?

Comment: @Igor not exactly sure what you're referring to. I have confirmed that when the images fail to load, `win.on('load resize scroll', function() {` is never called. So it's something to do with `var win` but I'm not sure what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `$(window).on('load', fn)` inside the `$(document).ready` callback. To quote the jQuery doc:

> Note that although the DOM always becomes ready before the page is fully loaded, it is usually not safe to attach a load event listener in code executed during a .ready() handler.

Better execute the loader function once unconditionally:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var win = $(window);
    function lazyload () {
        //...
    }
    win.on('resize scroll', lazyload);
    lazyload();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the issue! Although sometimes all images are loaded (not lazy-loaded).